# Autofill form with data from database when option selected - codeigniter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, codeigniter

I have table in database like below

```
id  |    service         |      rate         |      unit      |
 1        wifi                1,000                Mbps
 2     fiber optic            1,500                 Km
```

I also have a form like below

```
<form>
<select class="form-control" id="service">
   <option></option>
   <option value='1'>Wifi</option>
   <option value='2'>Fiber Optic</option>      
</select>


  <table>
     <tbody>
        <tr class="main">
            <td></td>
            <td>
                       <input type="text" name="service" class="form-control" placeholder="service">
            </td>
            <td>
                       <input type="text" name="rate" class="form-control" placeholder="Rate / Price">
            </td>
            <td>
                       <input type="text" name="unit" class="form-control" placeholder="Mbps/Km">
            </td>
           </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
    </form>
```

I want to add `value` into table automatically based on `select option` value.

Do you know how to add or show it ?

Thank you

Comment: your html table is invalid - no closing `tbody`  or `tr` tags

Answer (score 0):

Using some basic PHP to emulate a database lookup and some vanilla javascript you would typically do something like this. Send an Ajax request to a PHP script that does a lookup in the database based upon the value/id sent in the request. Let the PHP script send a response containing the correct data and then use the ajax callback to populate the form fields.

```
<?php

    /* To emulate a database lookup */
    $dbtable=array(
        1   =>  (object)array('service' => 'wifi', 'rate' => 1000, 'unit' => 'mbps'),
        2   =>  (object)array('service' => 'fibre optic', 'rate' => 1500 , 'unit' => 'km')
    );


    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset( $_POST['id'] ) ){
        ob_clean();

        $obj=array_key_exists( $_POST['id'], $dbtable ) ? $dbtable[ $_POST['id'] ] : false;

        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        exit( $obj ? json_encode( $obj ) : $obj );
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Set Form field values based upon selected option</title>
        <script>

            const ajax=function(url,params,callback){
                let xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.onload=function(){
                    if( this.status==200 && this.readyState==4 )callback.call( this, this.response )
                };
                xhr.open( 'POST', url, true );
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                xhr.send( params );
            };

            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{
                document.querySelector('select[id="service"]').addEventListener('change',function(e){
                    ajax( location.href, 'id='+this.value, function(r){
                        if( !r ){
                            alert( 'Bad foo!' );
                            return;
                        }
                        let json=JSON.parse( r );
                        Object.keys( json ).map( k=>{
                            let field=document.querySelector('input[name="'+k+'"]');
                            if( field )field.value=json[k]
                        })

                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select class='form-control' id='service'>
            <option selected disabled hidden>Please select service
            <option value=1>Wifi
            <option value=2>Fibre Optic
        </select>

        <table>
            <tr class='main'>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <input type='text' name='service' class='form-control' placeholder='service' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type='text' name='rate' class='form-control' placeholder='Rate / Price' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type='text' name='unit' class='form-control' placeholder='Mbps/Km' />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the table contains these two values only then you can get the value of selected option and fetch the result based on that.
Give a name to select --

```
<select class="form-control" id="service" name="service">
   <option></option>
   <option value='1'>Wifi</option>
   <option value='2'>Fiber Optic</option>
```

In your php file --

```
$selectedOption = $_REQUEST['service'];  //this will store the value of option 

$con=mysqli_connect("server","username","password","db_name");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM table_name where id = $selectedOption");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
     <th>Firstname</th>
     <th>Lastname</th> 
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<tr>"; 
    echo "<td><input value='" . $row['service'] . "'></td>";
    echo "<td><input value='" . $row['rate'] . "'></td>";
    echo "<td><input value='" . $row['unit'] . "'</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($con);  
?>
```

if Your table is dynamic then try to get the text of option selected 
`<option value="wifi">wifi</option>`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use Jquery. So that you can trigger an ajax request to your controller. In your controller you get the option selected and fatch data from your database table with model. Then return data from controller to ajax request and repopulate the html form with. 
Here is an example.
trigger ajax request to controller from html page.

```
$( document ).ready(function() { 
    $('#service').change(function(){
       var selectedValue = $(this).val();
         $.ajax({
               method: "POST",
               url: "url-to-controller",
               dataType:"json",
               data: { 'service': selectedValue },
               success:function(data){
                   //get json data and populate html form

                }
            })
       });
  });
```

In your controller get json data, decode it. Then fatch with model from DB. then return as json data.

```
   $service = $_POST['service'];
   $service_info = array();
   if(!empty($service)){
     //get data from model
      $service_info = $data_from_model;
   }
   header('Content-Type: application/json');//set header
   if(!empty($service_info)){       
        echo json_encode(array('result'=>1,'service_name' =>            
        $service_info['name'],'rate'=>$service_info['rates'], 
        'units'=>$service_info['units']));
   }else{
         echo json_encode(array('result'=>0));
    }
```

Comment: Hi @infomasud, so how I convert json data into table in the form ?

Comment: Try:  var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);

Comment: @lkramShabri You should put id attribute to all of your input fields. Then try:  var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);  if(jsonData.result==1){  $("#service_input_id").val(jsonData.service_name);    }